# My background php script needs to execute javascript. How?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, background, server-side

Here's what I'm working with...

Some javascript (let's call it 'apples.js') is executed client-side, and one of the things I'd like to do within that javascript is use Ajax to run a php script in the background. That much is easy enough.

The php script I'm working with was based off of a php page with data fields and a call to a js function at the end which saves the data. (Let's call this other js file 'bananas.js') I would like to populate the fields of the background php file by passing data from apples.js to the php file. My dillema is that my php file needs to execute a function within bananas.js at the end, but I don't think this will work if the php file is running in the background. Obviously I have to call the bananas.js function by some method other than an onclick, but even so, I don't think javascript can be run in the background. **Is that correct? Is there a simple way of handling this?**

I guess worst-case-scenario, I'll have to adapt the function from bananas.js into apples.js and skip the PHP intermediary script. I'm hoping I can avoid this because I'd prefer to work within the existing framework of this software and keep things simple (also I'm not terribly concerned programming efficiency; this software is being developed as part of my company's private portal).

Comment: " I don't think JavaScript can be run in the background" - I don't understand what that means. JavaScript is _event_ based. Is there actual _navigation_ in here?  (That is, switching pages in the traditional way?). I'm not sure I completely understand the problem and I'm slightly confused. Would you mind elaborating on the program's flow? (Like user clicks x, an ajax is sent to ... )

Comment: Http works as follows: You make a reuest from the browser and the server returns something or not. If there is nothing returned, there will be no more client stuff executed

Comment: You could always add something like `<script>bananaFunction();</script>` at the end of content generated by php when it sees that request has been made by `AJAX`.

Comment: Actually @Benjamin, you *can* now run JavaScript in the background. Check out web workers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers. Other than that, mplungian is right. Once your JavaScript is running the PHP that served it is no longer running (or shouldn't be). There's nothing to stop you issuing a fresh request though once you've run apples.js that calls bananas.js - in fact I suspect that's what you *should* do.

Comment: @cirrus When did I say anything implying I was not aware of web workers? All I said is that I did not understand what OP meant here, or what he was trying to accomplish. (If you check my profile I have _several_ answers that use web workers by the way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use a callback on your ajax method.

If you're using jQuery...

**apples.js**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        val1: 'one', 
        val2: 'two'
    },
    success: function (data) { //data is what is being returned by the .php script
        //now call your bananas.js function and pass in your data
        callBananas(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
    }
});
```

**bananas.js**

```
var callBananas = function(data) {
    //Do something...
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.
I originally wanted to make use of the intermediary php file which already existed so that I could have a quick and dirty solution. Instead I just took a couple hours to handle it all in javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general, calling JavaScript from PHP is not worth the trouble.

Just reimplement the function in PHP.